# How to close all windows of MacOS Finder EXCEPT the foreground window

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut, automation

The number of times I want to drop something from the Finder to another application but I'm stopped by endless open windows below. I have never found a simple shortcut to close them all except for the active one.

Could this be scripted?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there isn't a keyboard short-cut to hide all windows except the foreground window. macOS hides *applications* not individual windows of an application (and the Finder is just an app).

What you can do is <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> to your target application after grabbing the item in the Finder. Basically once you "grab" a file, don't let go of it, but rather, use the application switcher (invoked by <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>) to swap to the application you want to drop the file into.

Once the app is highlighted in the app switcher, release the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd> keys, which will bring your app and it's windows forward, then you can drop the file on your target window.

I made a quick GIF to show this in action:

[image: Grab Option/Alt-tab to drop in your App]